# String comparison in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi here I'm trying to compare my textbox value with a string in winforms application (c#). What is the best way to do it?

```
if(myText.Value == "xyz")
```

In asp.net we can move the "xyz" string constant to a resource file and then we will compare with that. According to coding practices that is the best practice.

But in winform is there any way to move this constant to a resource file?

Comment: You can work with Resources in WinForms applications the same way as you do in web applications.

Comment: So is the question about string comparison or the creation of resource files? The title leads me to believe the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the documentation: [Adding and Editing Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

When you add your string to your `Resources` you can access it like this:

```
var value = myProject.Properties.Resources.StringName;

if(myText.Value == value)
{ 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we can also compare the text in your text box by using the .Text Extension for the textBox control.

if(myText.Text == "xyz")

{

// required code

}

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking for? String comparison is done the way you did it or with a `stringObject.Equals()` method with some additional parameters. Constant literals should be moved to resource file and then accessed by `Properties.Resources.YourStringVariableName`